# What can tunnel through a graphene sheet?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-tunneling

In popularizations, people tunnel through walls or doors.  But what can really tunnel through a graphene sheet without tearing it?

According to Wikipedia, a single layer of graphene absorbs 2.3 % of white light, but 97% makes it through.  It conducts electrons well enough to make a transistor.

I doubt that a baseball tunnels through a sheet of graphene without harming it.
But what about a Buckyball? or a smaller molecule?  A helium atom? A bare proton?

This looks deceptively like the one dimensional finite barrier problem in elementary QM textbooks.  Can we calculate the probability of a given projectile at a given velocity tunnelling through the graphene sheet?  Is there any experimental data?

Comment: Bloody Helium atoms get through all kinds of stuff, a fact which is a constant pain in the neck for particle experimenters. Especially as helium can have adverse effects on PMTs (see the "Handling precautions section of http://jp.hamamatsu.com/products/sensor-etd/pd002/pd395/index_en.html for instance).

Comment: Yes, I knew that. But I don't know if or how fast they go through graphene.  Also is that tunnelling or is it diffusion?  Is there a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even helium atoms (at reasonable temperatures) do not tunnel through graphene, as the potential energy barrier is far too high.  (source: [Leenaerts et al. 2008](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.3021413))

However, suitably small holes may allow for tunneling of helium atoms through graphene-like materials at room temperature and below  (source: [Schrier 2010](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jz100748x), [Hauser and Schwerdtfeger 2012](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jz201504k))

For protons, the barrier height is much lower, so tunneling can be appreciable. (source: [Miao et al. 2013](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/C3CP52318G) )